# UDP vs TCP : sending small data

Tags: tcp, udp

I need to send two double values and one integer value per Wifi.

I need about 25 packets a second.
If one of them get´s lost its no problem. But it should never happen, that 10 out of 25 gets lost.

Is that possible?

What do you recommend to use? UDP or TCP?

Comment: UDP has no guarantees that the packages will be delivered, but the headers are smaller than TCP. It also has no handshake or acknowledgements. I don't think the question is relevant. You should make the choice yourself. Thy to examine your requirements, prioritize them and then make a choice considering the specs (bandwidth, reliability, speed, etc..). I would say that UDP could do the job, unless there is a high package loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of packet loss in Wifi really depends on many factors: equipment, distances from the access point, activity of peers and so on.

40% packet loss (10/25) is rather extreme, but may happen in the right (actually: wrong) setting.

You didn't mention what is the impact of using TCP for your system. Is the overhead is a problem? if not - I would recommend using TCP until proved an extra performance gain is required, and only then consider moving to UDP.

Sort of avoiding "premature optimization".

Comment: TCP for checking the sender as a security feature. But this is not necessary. But if TCP is fast enougth then I would prefer to use this one.

Comment: The network itself shouldn't have a problem sending 25 packets a second, regularly. It mostly the software that can limit it. Just test it.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much *can't* use TCP for this because a single packet lost will trigger waiting and retransmission, taking seconds. A single lost packet will totally interrupt your message flow.